# OpenVAS certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, certificates

I have an error when trying to rebuild my openvas database that appears to be caused by a certificate problem. I'm out of the usual debugging I'd so and I'm at a loss as to what is going on.

Here's the command I wanted to run.

```
server# openvasmd --rebuild --progress
Rebuilding NVT cache... failed.
```

Checking `openvasmd.log` I find the following, indicating I need to update my certificates.

```
lib  ... openvas_server_verify: the certificate is not trusted
lib  .... openvas_server_verify: the certificate hasn't got a known issuer
```

On double checking the commands I rebuild the server and user certificates with the following:

```
openvas-mkcert -q -f
openvas-mkcert-client -n -i
```

The server cert files it creates all show today's date and time. The four files that it creates all show today's date and time.

/var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem
/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/cakey.pem
/var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem
/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem

I restarted the manager daemon using strace to be sure that these certificates are right.

```
server# strace -f -e open openvasmd 2>&1 | grep pem
open("/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

I then checked that the server certificate is indeed valid:

```
server# openssl verify -CAfile /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem
/var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem: OK
```

By all rights this should be working. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Execute this:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem /var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem

openssl verify -CAfile /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem

openssl verify -CAfile /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem /var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem
```

And the solution is:

```
openvasmd --modify-scanner $(openvasmd --get-scanners) --scanner-ca-pub /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem --scanner-key-pub /var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem --scanner-key-priv /var/lib/openvas/private/CA/clientkey.pem
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. The EPEL RPM package paths are a bit different though. Certs are stored in /etc/pki/openvas/CA, keys in /etc/pki/openvas/private/CA. So the command that I used was:
 
`openvasmd --modify-scanner $(openvasmd --get-scanners) --scanner-ca-pub /etc/pki/openvas/CA/cacert.pem --scanner-key-pub /etc/pki/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem --scanner-key-priv /etc/pki/openvas/private/CA/clientkey.pem`